# How to make left,right bracket in table view?

Tags: iphone

I saw some applications have < something > in table view cell.
If I press left or right bracket, something(text or graphic) between them are changed.
It is used in setting menu.
How can I make that? Is there any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   

UIImageView *imgView;   
UIImageView *imgView1; 
UILabel     *lblName;   
if(cell == nil)   
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(5,0,20,62)];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"leftimg.png"]];
    imgView.tag = 55;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];

    lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 100, 25)];
    lblName.tag = 77;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblName];
    [lblName release];

    imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(200,0,20,62)];
    [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightimg.png"]];
    imgView1.tag = 66;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];
    [imgView1 release];
}  
else    
{  
    imgView = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:55];  
    imgView1 = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:66];  
    lblName = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:77];  

}
lblName.text = @"your text";

return cell;
```

}

Comment: I almost got it. There is text before left bracket and text or grahic between brackets. I still don't konw how to put it between brackets. I am beginner. It looks like this: text < image or text >

Comment: as you put imageview as per my code , put UILabel between images and write it .

Comment: i have eddited my answer .use it it will work for u.  and change position according to ur need...

Comment: If I want text between brackets, I use UILabel. If I want image between brackets, do I make another image view? right?

Comment: Last question. Do I have to subclass from UIImageView to respond when I touch bracket?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom tableview cell by subclassing UITableViewCell and adding two buttons to the cell view.

Comment: It depends on your exact view. There are lots of examples around the web and on SO; http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+UITableViewCell